# Trouble with mkdir and ofstream

Tags: c++, cygwin, mkdir, ofstream

This is my first time working with directories.

I have this code snippet:

```
void initialize()
{
  mkdir("/cydrive/c/enc/user", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
  mkdir("/cygdrive/c/enc/misc", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
  ofstream user ("/cygdrive/c/enc/misc/usercount.txt");
  if (user.is_open())
    user << "0 0" << endl;
  user.close();
  ofstream prompt ("/cygdrive/c/enc/misc/prompt.txt");
  if (prompt.is_open())
    prompt << "CLI>";
  prompt.close();  
  ofstream randomuser ("/cydrive/c/enc/user/rando.txt");
  if (randomuser.is_open())
    randomuser << "garbageinfo";
  randomuser.close();
}
```

The user and prompt ofstreams are behaving exactly as I intend, but whenever I try to open an enc/user directory it simply will not open. This inconsistency is driving me crazy, any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `mkdir()` is failing due to a typo in the directory name. I think:

```
mkdir("/cydrive/c/enc/user", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
```

should be:

```
mkdir("/cygdrive/c/enc/user", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
          ^
```

If not, check the return value of `mkdir()` to ensure success:

```
if (0 != mkdir("/cydrive/c/enc/user", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) &&
    EEXIST != errno)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create directory: "<< strerror(errno) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A million thanks to you! My tired eyes could not catch something so simple. I would vote up but I'm brand new round these parts.

Comment: If this solved it can you accept the answer (by clicking the tick outline next to the answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?